# Create a programming language with C#

Tags: c#, programming-languages

First of all, I want a programming language to make interactions between that language and my application environment. I wrote something that just knows `if`, `void` and `function`, variables with their scopes and of course invoke built-in functions which they are all working perfectly. But now, I'm stuck with some parts and realized that I can't continue with just simple text parsing and there are many things that I can't do.

So for that, I searched about this topic and I got [Creating programming language using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx). It was fine but I have two problems with it.

1. I can't understand it.
2. It generates Console codes but I want to use them in a Windows Forms Application.

For short, Is there anyone who knows how I can make a language without learning about Lexers, Reflections ...

Thanks.

Comment: " _For short, Is there anyone knows how can I make my own language without passing courses like lexer, reflections ... _" ... umm, no. You will need to learn the basics to understand how to create your own truly unique language. What do you need this for ? Remember, we have the DLR, that allows you to embed a scripting language into an app, would that be sufficient for you ?

Comment: Is this a learning task? Or are you actually trying to **do** something. If the latter, there are a lot of scripting languages you can use inside c# - the "irons" (iron python, iron ruby, etc), boo, f#, JavaScript engines; probably lua, etc...

Comment: It's not learning task and I need this for my engine!. I made a nice 2d level editor I think and I want to interact with it with codes. DLR? hmm, I think I saw it but never knows its name. Oh! DLR I forgot what was that, yeah but I never tried to embed. I should try it.

Comment: Then my advice: use something that already exists, and spend your time writing the stuff that is unique to your project, rather than writing an engine. Doing this stuff **well** is really really hard and takes expert knowledge. Doing it poorly is just "hard" and will be buggy and slow.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I really understand your question.

Is this to be an extension of your program? A collection of library functions written in C#?

Or a completely separate language for which you are writing an interpreter in C#? (which is what I guess)

If it is the latter, in the good old days I would have pointed you at Lex/Yacc (GIYF).

Right now, I can only say ANTLR.  Check out the [Five minute introduction to ANTLR 3](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3) and [ANTLR v3 C# Code generator and Runtime library](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target)

Just check out the screen shots of the IDE on this  page

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks so nice! I'll try it now.

Comment: LInks are broken? I am looking to make a macro language system in a unity3d game I plan to create...

Comment: The links for Antrl3 are broken because it is now Antrl4. Google is your friend ;-) Believe me, it will be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your own language is possible but very challenging. You can't do it well without things like lexers.

Creating your own language also forces your clients to learn yet another language, and there will be no extant third party code or libraries for this putative language.

An alternative would be to embed an existing language and expose your application's functionality through that. Python is one very common choice for embedding but there are many other options. I strongly recommend that, for this task, you consider embedding an existing language rather than inventing your own.

Comment: Yup, That's right. Thanks for reply.